# Netatalk sharing filename limitation

Tags: file-sharing, afp, netatalk

I want to share file from my linux box to OSX clients. **I don't want to use SMB !**

I'm using netatalk 2.1.2 but apparently there is a filname length limitation :

I've tried "123456789012345678901234567.avi" (31 characters long), and it works but when the filename is >31 char long. Some programs like Quicktime can't open the file.

I've started the share with :

```
... -unixcodepage utf8 -maccodepage utf8
```

Is there any way to make netatalk/afpd to work with filenames longer than 31 char ?

Comment: Good question, there. 2.1.2 supports AFP v3.2 which should support longer filenames. But for some reason, it looks like clients are failing back (or are starting) at AFP 2.something, which is limited to 31 character names.

Comment: netatalk is very old and IMHO, poorly maintained at least some years ago.  i had frequent problems with CNID backends on BDB, sometimes even losing the whole CNID data.  i see some recent updates on the website; but once bitten...  i had _much_ better experience with NFS, and faster throughput in most cases too.

Comment: @ Javier Nice objective opinion ! So I've tried the NFS solution but some problems remain : Can you advertise the NFS shares with AVAHI(mDNS) so they appear in the MacOSX Finder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a issue with netatalk 2.1.2 ! After upgrading to 2.1.3 everything is fine.